# Javascript: Adding Slider that moves dependent on user input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Within my web app I wish to add a slider that moves dependent on input from user.

For example something that looks like [this](http://nowtheme.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/animated-progress-bar_thumb.jpg).

What are some resources/examples I can use for this?

Comment: You can create it using Javascript or you can use jquery ui slider https://jqueryui.com/slider/.

Comment: just refer in google.. after tried so far.. you will post here for programming issues..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at bootstrap progress bars, you can change them dynamically.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress